# Why does Debug DrawRay not draw the Ray I'm Expecting?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

So i saw a few tutorials and wrote a similar code but i cant get the raycast to work for me.
I need the raycast to see if my char is grounded to enable the jump.
Here is the program:

```
private bool isGrounded()
{
    float extraHeightText = .01f;
    RaycastHit2D raycastHit = Physics2D.Raycast(GetComponent<Collider2D>().bounds.center, Vector2.down, GetComponent<Collider2D>().bounds.extents.y + extraHeightText);
    Color rayColor;
    if (raycastHit.collider != null)
    {
        rayColor = Color.green;
    } 
    else
    {
        rayColor = Color.red;
    }
    Debug.DrawRay(GetComponent<Collider2D>().bounds.center, Vector2.down * (GetComponent<Collider2D>().bounds.extents.y + extraHeightText));
    return raycastHit.collider != null;
}
```

Comment: And where are you calling that function from?

Answer (score 0):

`Debug.DrawRay` will only draw using gizmos. These are *enabled* in the "Scene" view by default and *disabled* in the "Game" view by default.  [The documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawRay.html) states:

> The line will be drawn in the Scene view of the editor. If gizmo drawing is enabled in the game view, the line will also be drawn there.

If it's drawing in neither view, make sure your function is being called from somewhere. You might also need to enable the particular script's gizmos in the drop-down menu. Also, keep in mind this feature will *never* work in a Standalone build of the game; `Debug.DrawRay` only functions in the Editor.

I'll also note that the "extra height" value of `0.01f` is exceptionally small.

Gizmos Disabled:
[image: Gizmos Disabled]
Gizmos Enabled:
[image: Gizmos Enabled]